# HTML form submitting twice

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I've read most of the posts with similar issues, but can't seem to find an example or answer that exactly matches my situation.

I have a form with some required fields. When the form submits I want the validation to occur. But I don't want a default "submit" button or action. Instead, I have a generic Button object.

When I refer to "validation", I'm talking about the default action that occurs if inputs marked "required" have not been selected/filled. First question, can this validation be "called" with a method? Because I believe my problem is that I couldn't get it to fire except by clicking a submit button.

So, in my code, I have a hidden submit button, and then a generic button that performs a "click()" on the hidden submit. This fires the validation but I also believe it submits the form. I have the form's onsubmit value set to "return postCheckout();", and the function does a "return false", but I think it happens too late, after the form submit() fires and then the function fires... I need a way out of this mess!

HTML markup:

```
<form id="frmCheckout" onsubmit="return postCheckout();">
<table id="tblHeader">
<tr>
<td>
<select name="tblDevelopers" id="tblDevelopers" required>
<option value="" disabled selected>Who are you?</option>
<option value="1">Black</option>
<option value="2">Buntjer</option>
<option value="3">Dwyer</option><
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<span style="display: none;">
<input type="submit" id="btn_frmCheckout" />
</span>
<button onclick="$( '#btn_frmCheckout' ).click();">Check Out</button>
</td>
</tr>  
</table>
</form>
```

The script:

```
function postCheckout() {
  $( "#dialog-PleaseWait" ).dialog({
    show: { effect: "highlight", color: "#99ccff", duration: "10000"},
    resizable: false,
    height:200,
    width:260,
    modal: false,
              buttons:
          {
            "OK": function()
            { $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
  });
  $( ".ui-dialog-title" ).text("Please wait");
  $( ".ui-dialog-content" ).html("Copying Template Files. <img style='border:0; padding-left: 10px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:0px;' src='/htmlFiles/loader.gif' />");
  $( "#dialog-PleaseWait" ).dialog("open");

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'checkout',
    data:$('#frmCheckout').serialize(), success: function() {window.close();}
    });

  return false;
}
```

Comment: try changing your <button> to be an <input type="button"> instead, see if anything changes.  Inside a form, <button> by default will submit the form.  Or just get rid of that guy and change your other guy to be a type="button" instead of a type="submit" and move the onsubmit logic to it as an onclick

Comment: Input type submit will submit the form. you must prevent the default berhavior or change the input submit to something else.

Comment: I've tried a variety of buttons... no change. It appears regardless of button types, that the HTML5 automatic validation of "required" field elements only fires on a submit() event, regardless of how it's invoked. However, even if that validation runs and fails, the AJAX function runs. It seems I cannot have both the automatic validation on submit, AND a function that runs on submit.

Answer (score 2):

Trying using event.preventDefault() within a on submit function. Instead of the onsubmit attribute.

```
$(document).on('submit','#frmCheckout',function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $( "#dialog-PleaseWait" ).dialog({
    show: { effect: "highlight", color: "#99ccff", duration: "10000"},
    resizable: false,
    height:200,
    width:260,
    modal: false,
              buttons:
          {
            "OK": function()
            { $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
  });
  $( ".ui-dialog-title" ).text("Please wait");
  $( ".ui-dialog-content" ).html("Copying Template Files. <img style='border:0; padding-left: 10px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:0px;' src='/htmlFiles/loader.gif' />");
  $( "#dialog-PleaseWait" ).dialog("open");

  var validator = $("#frmCheckout").validate(options);
  if (validator.form()) {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'checkout',
        data:$('#frmCheckout').serialize(), success: function() {window.close();}
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Won't this prevent the HTML5 "required' Automatic validation?

Comment: No, I don't believe so validation should still be present

Comment: The "automatic validation" of the form DOES fire, but so does the AJAX Post. My form only submits once now, but it submits even if the required fields are missing. I get a real quick "Please select an item from the list" message on the required field but the form immediately submits regardless. I've removed the action tag from the form, and all buttons, simply doing a form submit() on a hyperlink click now just to eliminate confusion with buttons and button types.

Comment: Edited answer. Use validator.form() check around ajax call.

Comment: Almost... I'm not using the Validator plugin, but the jquery checkValidity function is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery checkValidity() function was the missing piece for me. Almost, because it doesn't display the tooltip/caption for the user on required fields, but here's the code that both validates and does an AJAX post on a form.

```
function postCheckout() {

  if($('#frmCheckout')[0].checkValidity()) {

  $( "#dialog-PleaseWait" ).dialog({
    show: { effect: "highlight", color: "#99ccff", duration: "10000"},
    resizable: false,
    height:200,
    width:260,
    modal: false,
              buttons:
          {
            "OK": function()
            { $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
  });
  $( ".ui-dialog-title" ).text("Please wait");
  $( ".ui-dialog-content" ).html("Copying Template Files. <img style='border:0; padding-left: 10px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:0px;' src='/htmlFiles/loader.gif' />");
  $( "#dialog-PleaseWait" ).dialog("open");

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'checkout',
    data:$('#frmCheckout').serialize(), success: function() {window.close();}
    });

  }
  return false;
}
```

The HTML Form has no method, action, or onsubmit attributes, and no submit button. I have a generic button that calls postCheckout() onclick().

Thanks for all the help and the clues toward "checkValidity()". Now to dig deeper and see if I can get the default error captions to appear.

Comment: Removing the "return false;" solved the issue. Because I'm never actually initiating a form submit() event, there's no need to "return false". That statement was actually evaluated against the validation event, and returning false caused the caption/tooltips not to appear.